# Can sed search & replace on a match if that match in only part of a line?

Tags: sed

The sed below will output the input exactly. What I'd like to do is replace all occurrences of _ with - in the first matching group (\1), but not in the second. Is this possible?

```
echo 'abc_foo_bar=one_two_three' | sed 's/\([^=]*\)\(=.*\)/\1\2/'
abc_foo_bar=one_two_three
```

So, the output I'm hoping for is:

```
abc-foo-bar=one_two_three
```

I'd prefer not to resort to awk since I'm doing a string of other sed commands too, but I'll resort to that if I have to.

Edit: Minor fix to RE

Comment: Is your RE really what you intend? I'd have expected `\([^=]*])\(=.*\)`. That's what I based my answer on, but can adjust it if desired.

Comment: You're right, I've updated the question to reflect this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in sed using the hold space:

```
$ echo 'abc_foo_bar=one_two_three' | sed 'h; s/[^=]*//; x; s/=.*//; s/_/-/g; G; s/\n//g'
abc-foo-bar=one_two_three
```

Comment: I figured the answer would be in hold space somehow, I just didn't see how as I hadn't used it before. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk` instead of `sed` as follows:

```
echo 'abc_foo_bar=one_two_three' | awk -F= -vOFS== '{gsub("_", "-", $1); print $1, $2}'
```

The output would be, as expected:

```
abc-foo-bar=one_two_three
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ghc` instead of `sed` as follows:

```
echo "abc_foo_bar=one_two_three" | ghc -e "getLine >>= putStrLn . uncurry (++) . (map (\x -> if x == '_' then '-' else x) *** id) . break (== '=')"
```

The output would be, as expected:

```
abc-foo-bar=one_two_three
```

Comment: At least it's really more readable than any of the `sed` possible kludge.

Comment: Haha, nice. Though requiring people to install a Haskell compiler will make me rather unpopular in the office :)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
echo 'abc_foo_bar=one_two_three' | 
sed 's/^/\n/;:a;s/\n\([^_=]*\)_/\1-\n/;ta;s/\n//'
abc-foo-bar=one_two_three
```

Or this:

```
echo 'abc_foo_bar=one_two_three' | 
sed 'h;s/=.*//;y/_/-/;G;s/\n.*=/=/'
abc-foo-bar=one_two_three
```